# TikZ: Calculating with angles

Tags: tikz-pgf

How do I define angles properly, so that I am able to calculate with them?

I tried the following code to get the following result, but the code won't compile.

Instead of writing `0.5\bdangle+0.5\dsangle` I want to write `0.5*(\bdangle+\dsangle)` as seen below with `2/3*(\inangle+\mmangle)`. Even more tricky: How do I set the green dot where it is?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}

\newlength{\outerradius}\setlength{\outerradius}{10cm}
\newlength{\innerradius}\setlength{\innerradius}{9cm}
\newlength{\radiusstep}\setlength{\radiusstep}{5mm}
\newcommand{\bdangle}{90}
\newcommand{\dsangle}{190}
\newcommand{\mmangle}{230}
\newcommand{\inangle}{330}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[fill, circle, radius=1mm] at (0,0) {};
\draw (0,0) circle[radius=\innerradius];
\draw (0,0) circle[radius=\outerradius];

\node[fill=yellow, circle]  at (\bdangle:0.5\outerradius+0.5\innerradius) {a};
\node[fill=yellow, circle]  at (\dsangle:0.5\outerradius+0.5\innerradius) {b};
\node[fill=yellow, circle]  at (\mmangle:0.5\outerradius+0.5\innerradius) {c};
\node[fill=yellow, circle]  at (\inangle:0.5\outerradius+0.5\innerradius) {d};

\node[fill=red, circle]     at (0.5\bdangle+0.5\dsangle):\innerradius-\radiusstep) {};
\node[fill=blue, circle]    at (2/3*(\inangle+(1-2/3)*\mmangle):\innerradius-\radiusstep) {};
\node[fill=green, circle]   at (0.5*(\bdangle+360-\inangle):\innerradius-\radiusstep) {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of using regular brackets for the calculations, have you tried enclosing them in curly brackets, like `{  }`? Also, I'm not sure what you mean when you say *"How do I set the green dot where it is?"*

Comment: @Alenanno: Well, you see where the green dot is in the image. And if I calculate (330°-90°)/2 I get 120° not 60° - and I want the green dot at 60°.

Comment: @Alenanno: `\node[fill=red, circle] at ({0.5\bdangle+0.5\dsangle}:\innerradius-\radiusstep) {};` does not work if that is what you mean.

Comment: `(330-90)/2` gives 120, you need to do `(330-90)/4` to get 60. And yeah, the curly brackets don't work. mmmh, maybe you could use `\pgfmath` commands, but I feel there is an easier way. :D

Comment: @Alenanno: Maybe you can post as solution with `\pgfmath`?

Comment: Try `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` and `($ 2/3*(\inangle+\mmangle) )$`?

Comment: @Andrew: This does not work, or I misunderstand how do insert this. Could you give a MWE?

Comment: @Make42 Try `({0.5*\bdangle+0.5*\dsangle}:{\innerradius-\radiusstep})`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load the `calc` library, then enclose the full operations between curly brackets `{}` (regular brackets won't work), otherwise TikZ will think that `2/3` is a shape name, which it obviously is not.

```
\node[fill=red, circle] at ({0.5*\dsangle+0.5*\bdangle}:\innerradius-\radiusstep) {};
\node[fill=blue, circle] at ({2/3*\inangle+(1-2/3)*\mmangle)}:\innerradius-\radiusstep) {};
\node[fill=green, circle] at ({0.5*(\bdangle+\inangle)+180)}:\innerradius-\radiusstep) {};
```

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=10pt]{standalone}  

\newlength{\outerradius}\setlength{\outerradius}{10cm}
\newlength{\innerradius}\setlength{\innerradius}{9cm}
\newlength{\radiusstep}\setlength{\radiusstep}{5mm}
\newcommand{\bdangle}{90}
\newcommand{\dsangle}{190}
\newcommand{\mmangle}{230}
\newcommand{\inangle}{330}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[fill, circle, radius=1mm] at (0,0) {};
\draw (0,0) circle[radius=\innerradius];
\draw (0,0) circle[radius=\outerradius];

\node[fill=yellow, circle]  at (\bdangle:0.5\outerradius+0.5\innerradius) {a};
\node[fill=yellow, circle]  at (\dsangle:0.5\outerradius+0.5\innerradius) {b};
\node[fill=yellow, circle]  at (\mmangle:0.5\outerradius+0.5\innerradius) {c};
\node[fill=yellow, circle]  at (\inangle:0.5\outerradius+0.5\innerradius) {d};

\node[fill=red, circle] at ({0.5*\dsangle+0.5*\bdangle}:\innerradius-\radiusstep) {};
\node[fill=blue, circle] at ({2/3*\inangle+(1-2/3)*\mmangle)}:\innerradius-\radiusstep) {};
\node[fill=green, circle] at ({0.5*(\bdangle+\inangle)+180)}:\innerradius-\radiusstep) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not working. Could you give a MWE?

Comment: @Make42 See edit.

Comment: It compiles and displays the points as you have shown, but as you can see, the points are at the wrong place - something did not work with your calculations... what is it?

Comment: @Make42 I only used your calculations, so I assumed that's where you wanted them. Where do you want the colored circles?

Comment: I wanted them as shown in the image - my calculations have been wrong :-).

Comment: @Make42 So the image I posted is what you wanted? I'm confused. :D

Comment: I did a mistake when I asked my question: I wanted the picture from my question, but the code I showed in my question does not generate that, but instead what you showed in your picture. You oriented yourself by my code, not my picture (which is okay). However to get the picture from my question one has to change the calculation presented by you and me.

Comment: @Make42 Ah I got it. Well, at what angles are those circles in your image? That way I can fix mine too. :D

Comment: I changed my code.